# React Native Image Shadow Color

Tags: image, react-native, shadow, blur

I'm working on a mobile app with React-Native and I need to implement a new component.

The exemple :

[image]

So, my question is, how can i add this shadow / blur image on my component ?

I know how to make a blur on an image but how can i do this effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so,basically you work with two images, opacity, blurRadius and position absolute.

try :

```
<View style={{elevation:12, position:'absolute', left:100, top:100, elevation:12, borderRadius:50, borderWidth: 1, borderColor:'rgba(255, 255, 2555, 0.4)',  overflow: 'hidden',  opacity:0.3}}>
    <Image blurRadius={10} style={{width:300, height:150}} source={{uri:'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-garden-flowers-450w-257560639.jpg'}} />
</View>            
<View style={{position:'absolute', left:95, top:90, borderRadius:50, borderWidth: 0, borderColor:'rgba(255, 255, 2555, 0.4)',   overflow: 'hidden'}}>
    <Image style={{width:300, height:150, }} source={{uri:'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-garden-flowers-450w-257560639.jpg'}} />
</View>
```

Comment: Hey Sergio, thanks a lot, I succeed to do this part, but not the gaussian blur on the image which is in back! Do you know how to do it ? Thanks

Comment: Finaly i used your code and add it react-native-blur package and it works well!

Comment: @Clowning How did you do to make it work with `react-native-blur`? I don't have the good result. Can you show me a code snippet please?